# Question about diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I have a question regarding a part in a book of Pattern Recognition I'm reading.

In appendix of the book it is said that a positive definite symmetric matrix $A$ can be diagonalized by the similarity transformation:

$$\Phi^TA\Phi = \Lambda$$

Where matrix $\Phi$ has as its columns the unit eigenvectors ($\textbf{v}_i^T\textbf{v}_i = 1$) of $A$, that is,
$$\Phi = [\textbf{v}_1, ..., \textbf{v}_n]$$

and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix with elements the corresponding eigenvalues of $A$. From the orthonormality of the eigenvectors it is obvious that $\Phi^T\Phi = I$.

Now few pages after this definition it is said that:

Now let $A$ be a symmetric matrix. Then, as we know from earlier in the appendix, it can be diagonalized, that is,

$$A = \Phi^T\Lambda\Phi$$

where $\Phi$ is the orthogonal matrix with columns the orthonormal eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ the diagonal matrix having the corresponding eigenvalues on its diagonal.

Now I got confused at this part...shouldn't it be:

$$\Phi^TA\Phi = \Lambda \Leftrightarrow \Phi\Phi^TA\Phi\Phi^T = \Phi\Lambda\Phi^T$$

Or does $$\Phi\Lambda\Phi^T = \Phi^T\Lambda\Phi$$

Is there a typo in the book or is there something I missed. This maybe a silly question, but I got confused.

Thank you for nay help :)

P.S. If anyone is interested I'm reading the book **Pattern Recognition 4th edition by Sergios Theodoridis** and the parts I'm confused can be found at pages: 928 and 933 :)

**UPDATE**, I added the parts from the book here as an image just to make it clearer :)

[image]

Comment: $\Phi^T A \Phi = \Lambda$ for $\Phi$ orthogonal iff $A = \Phi \Lambda \Phi^T$, and similarly, $A = \Psi^T \Lambda \Psi$ for $\Psi$ orthogonal iff $\Lambda = \Psi A \Psi^T$. Seriously, they were just being sloppy, and in the first instance used $\Phi$ and in the second instance replaced $\Phi$ by its transpose (i.e., used $\Psi = \Phi^T$).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @Branimir Ćaćić :) So you think the author was just sloppy and made a minor mistake?

Comment: That's not rare thing even in very serious books

Comment: Yes I have also noted that unfortunately :S

Comment: Not even necessarily the author—you'd be surprised at the errors the editors and typesetters sometimes introduced. I even once saw a paper where the journal's typesetters had inexplicably replaced every instance of $\oplus$ with an $\otimes$, in comparison with the authors' arXiv version.

Comment: @jjepsuomi Author is neither sloppy nor in error. A is symmetric so $$\Phi\Lambda\Phi^T= \Phi^T\Lambda\Phi$$. Check my derivation in answer.

Comment: @Branimir Ćaćić That sucks... :P

Comment: @Branimir Ćaćić +1 Thank you for that x) I checked it myself also just now :) $\Phi^TA\Phi = \Lambda \Leftrightarrow A = \Phi\Lambda\Phi^T$. $A$ is symmetric so $A = A^T = (\Phi\Lambda\Phi^T)^T = (\Phi^T)^T\Lambda^T\Phi^T = \Phi\Lambda\Phi^T$.

Comment: @jjepsuomi I was confused too when it was voted down. My Answer is up again.

Comment: @kaka No problem :) Thank you for your help anyway! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this book when we find $\Phi^TA\Phi = \Lambda$ and after few pages we find $\Phi A\Phi^T = \Lambda$ this doesn't mean that we deal with the same matrix so the matrix $\Phi$ in the former equality isn't the same matrix $\Phi$ in the last equality and if we change the notation in this last equality and we write $\Psi A\Psi^T=\Lambda$ then we have $\Psi=\Phi^T$.

Comment: No, they refer to $\Phi$ the same way as in previous statement.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @Sami Ben Romdhane so the author changed notation?

Comment: Yes he did. You're welcome.

Comment: +1 Thank you again. That clears it up, I can proceed now :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi Branimir is correct, I was wrong.

Comment: @kaka no problem :) All help is welcome :)